# Flutter - Storing Device Height as a Global Variable

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I'm Currently working on an Application, and my way of combating different screen sizes is dividing the Widget's heights and widths by some constant so that way I can ensure it looks the same across multiple devices.
Whenever I would want to do so, I have to call MediaQuery.of(context).size.height every time.
Is there a way to store this height as a global variable somewhere? I have a Variables.dart file where I store other variables like some colors and values, but I cannot use (context) there.
I don't want to call the Function over and over again

Any help would be appreciated, Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can get the device size without context like

```dart
MediaQueryData.fromWindow(window).size;
```

Also, you can check [flutter_screenutil](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_screenutil) for more.

Comment: But this line of code doesnt work anyways, because "window" isnt defined in my other file yeah?

Comment: This  comes from `import 'dart:ui';`